# rail_youbot_teleop and youBot arm are not working properly

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a Wiimote in conjunction with the rail_youbot nodes to control a KUKA youBot.
I recently had to update my youbot_oodl (using the "youbot_wii_teleop.launch" node).
After the update, I can no longer operate the arm of the youBot using the Wiimote. The base of the youBot functions however (I can drive it around just fine).
I have done a "rostopic echo /joy" and see that the Wiimote is in-fact publishing data.
I can also calibrate the arm (and the arm moves) using both the "roslaunch rail_youbot_launch rail_youbot.launch" and "sudo ./base_arm_gripper_test". Interestingly, I can do position control using the youBot mobile app found on the youbot-store website.

I've restored back to the original reinstalled the youbot_driver, remade all packages, and remade the rail_youbot package as well.

The youBot is plugged in.

I'm at a bit of a loss of what to look at next.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65705/rail_youbot_teleop-and-youbot-arm-are-not-working-properly/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2013-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2013-06-21**:
I've also run the "youbot_arm_test" node (found in youbot-ros-pkg). This should allow me to do postion control, by typing in radian values for each of the joints... this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wait. Never mind. Turns out that the new youbot_oodl doesn't contain all of the sub-nodes as the old youbot_oodl. Ie, missing dependency

---

Originally posted by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) with karma: 162 on 2013-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0